# Ingress fanout gets Error: Server Error The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have 2 services. I want to create ingress fanout for them. 1 service runs properly, the other one  says

> Error: Server Error
> The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
>
> Please try again in 30 seconds.

I opened all firewall settings. here are some details

```
bahaddin@b k get ingress -n ingress-nginx 


NAME             CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE

fanout-ingress   <none>   *       35.201.67.49   80      2m57s


bahaddin@bahaddin-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-2:~/projects/personal/exposer/k8s-ingress$ k get svc -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.12.1.185    34.134.200.199   80:30803/TCP,443:32306/TCP   10m
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.12.0.83     <none>           443/TCP                      10m
web                                  NodePort       10.12.12.129   <none>           8080:30702/TCP               7m43s
web2                                 NodePort       10.12.5.55     <none>           8080:30160/TCP               7m42s
```

Here you see that external IP of ingress-nginx-controller (34.134.200.199) is different than fanout-ingress address. but when firstly the fanout-ingress has created , it was the same IP as ingress-nginx-controller (34.134.200.199). I cannot understand why, after some seconds it has gained the newer IP (35.201.67.49). I would be happy to get answer this as well.

The main question is , when I curl http://35.201.67.49/v2/ I get the result properly. But when I curl http://35.201.67.49/web1/hello - which is another service and defined on service, ingress and deployment files below -  is not reachable. When I curl 35.201.67.49/web1/hello i got an error

> Error: Server Error The server encountered a temporary error and could
> not complete your request.
>
> Please try again in 30 seconds.

fanput-ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: fanout-ingress
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /web1/*
            backend:
              serviceName: web
              servicePort: 8080
          - path: /v2/*
            backend:
              serviceName: web2
              servicePort: 8080
```

deployment and services

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: web
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: bago1/web1:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: web
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web2
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: web2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: web2
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: web2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: web
  type: NodePort

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web2
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: web2
  type: NodePort
```

Here [image: The result when I call API]

Comment: Your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The Ingress load balancer relies on Readiness & Liveness Probes of the Pods in order to determine which backens are ready to receive traffic.

Modify you Deployment YAML to look something like this - make sure to pick the right path on which you application returns HTTP 200 as a Status indicating a good health:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web2
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: web2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: web2
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: web2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 30
      periodSeconds: 30
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 30
      periodSeconds: 30
```